# How do I properly parse a string with a float values with a given number of decimal places into an integer?

Tags: java, math, floating-point, precision

I have float values with a given number of decimals. In this example 2 decimal places.

For example:

```
33.3
134.45
```

From those strings I want to have the following integer numbers:

```
3330
13445
```

I want to parse those strings to equivalent integer values using the fact that we known in advance the number of decimals. In this example is 2 so the actual float/double number needs to be multiplied by 100.

I have tried the following code but it parses `33.3` into `3329` instead of `3330`.

This is the code I have tried:

```java
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

        int decimalDigits = 2;
        String strNumber = "33.3";
        double doubleNumber = Double.parseDouble(strNumber);
        int intNumber = (int)(Double.parseDouble(strNumber) * (double)Math.pow(10,decimalDigits) );

        System.out.println(strNumber);
        System.out.println(doubleNumber);
        System.out.println(intNumber);

     }
}
```

And this is the result:

```
$javac HelloWorld.java
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M HelloWorld
33.3
33.3
3329
```

Comment: Parse to double, multiply by 100, and round to integer. Or read the string, find the period, remove it, and append zero, one, or two zeroes as needed to ensure there are two digits after where the period was, then parse to integer.

Answer (score 1):

To maintain precision, I recommend using [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
int decimalDigits = 2;
String strNumber = "33.3";
BigDecimal decimalNumber = new BigDecimal(strNumber);
int intNumber = decimalNumber.movePointRight(decimalDigits).intValue();

System.out.println(strNumber);
System.out.println(decimalNumber);
System.out.println(intNumber);
```

Output:

```
33.3
33.3
3330
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with regular floats or doubles? I need to parse hundreds of thousands of values and I guess BigDecimal is slower.

Comment: Don't prematurely optimize. Parsing hundreds of thousands of values is nothing for today's technology.

Comment: I did not measure it formally, but for a 3-4 seconds parsing task (around 10 million of numbers to be parsed from a file) I did not notice any performance penalty for using BigDecimal instead of floats.

Answer (score 0):

Use BigDecimal:

```
String res = new BigDecimal("33.3").multiply(new BigDecimal("10"))
  .setScale(0, ROUND_UNNECESSARY)
  .toPlainString()
```

Answer (score 0):

For a solution without `BigDecimal` this seems to work. I include it as reference in case someone else find it useful. I haven't tested which solution is faster and if I am missing anything else, any comment on potential issues on this way over BigDecimal usage is welcomed.

```java
(int)Math.round(Float.parseFloat(strNumber) * Math.pow(10,decimalDigits));
```